# Prove that: $\sqrt [3]{36}<\ln 28<\sqrt [3]{37}$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, inequality, reference-request, logarithms

> Prove that:
> $$\sqrt [3]{36}<\ln 28<\sqrt [3]{37}$$

This inequality is the result of an integral representation/inequality.

I lost access to the article that mentioned this inequality.  Now I want to prove it myself.  Using series is the standard way.  However, this involves heavy calculations, so it's almost useless. We know that,

$$\ln 28=2\ln 2+\ln 7$$

From here, it is necessary to evaluate the $\ln2$ and $\ln 7$ numbers independently. More work is required.

1. If you've seen this inequality before, please share the solution with us.  Presumably this will be the Integral representation.
2. If you have made any solution that requires as little computation as possible, please share it with us.
3. The question is open to all solutions involving elementary techniques or advanced techniques.

Less computational solutions are preferred.

Comment: Just hazarding a guess for a possible method, use the fact that as cuberoot an ln are both positive and monotonous increasing for inputs greater than 1, so that your statement is equivalent to $e^{\sqrt[3]{36}}<28<e^{\sqrt[3]{37}}$.  Then just look at the Taylor series for $e^{\sqrt[3]{x}}$

Comment: Numerically $\log 28$ matches $\sqrt[3]{37}$ upto an error of $1.73\times 10^{-5}$. The analysis will require reasonable amount of calculation.

Comment: it takes 14 terms for the taylor series of exp at $\sqrt[3]{37}$ to exceed 28

Answer (score 5):

**For the left inequality**:

We have
$$\ln 28 = 5 \ln 2 - \ln(8/7)
\ge 5\ln 2 - 1/7$$
where we have used $\ln(1 + u) \le u$ for all $u \ge 0$.

From
$$0 \le \int_0^1 \frac{x^2(1 - x)^3}{1 + x}\,\mathrm{d} x = 8\ln 2 - \frac{83}{15},$$
we have
$\ln 2 \ge \frac{83}{120}$.
(*Note*: Alternatively,
we may use $\ln \frac{1+x}{1-x}
\ge 2x + \frac23 x^3$ ($3$-th order Taylor approximation) to get
$\ln 2 \ge \frac{56}{81}$ by letting $x = 1/3$.)

Thus, we have
$$\ln 28 \ge 5 \cdot \frac{83}{120} - 1/7 = \frac{557}{168}.$$

Let $A = \sqrt[3]{36}$ and $B = 10/3$. Then $A < B$. We have
$$A = B - \frac{B^3 - A^3}{B^2 + BA + A^2} \le B - \frac{B^3 - A^3}{3B^2} = \frac{743}{225}.$$
(*Note*: $\sqrt[3]{36} = 3\sqrt[3]{1 + 1/3} \le 3(1 + 1/9) = 10/3$ by Bernoulli inequality.)

Since $\frac{743}{225} < \frac{557}{168}$, we have $36^{1/3} < \ln 28$.

$\phantom{2}$

**For the right inequality**:

Using $37 \cdot 27 = 999$, we have
$$\sqrt[3]{37} = \sqrt[3]{999/27} = \frac{10}{3}\sqrt[3]{999/1000}
\ge \frac{10}{3} \cdot \frac{3 \cdot 999/1000}{2\cdot 999/1000 + 1} = \frac{4995}{1499}$$
where we have used
$$u^{1/3} = \frac{u}{\sqrt[3]{u \cdot u \cdot 1}} \ge \frac{u}{(u+u+1)/3} = \frac{3u}{2u + 1}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\ln 28 < \frac{4995}{1499}.$$

I don't have a nice approach to deal with it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice answer +1. What motivated the inequalities, especially the integral?

Comment: @IMOPUTFIE Thanks! I learned this integral trick in this site. From positive integers $m, n$, $0 \le \int_0^1 \frac{x^m(1-x)^n}{1+x} \, \mathrm{d} x = a  + b\ln 2$ for some rational numbers $a, b$.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying an approximation with the simple tools...

$$\ln28=3\left(\ln(1+\frac{1}{2})-\ln(1-\frac{1}{2})\right)+\ln(1+\frac{1}{27})\approx3\sum_{n=0}^{N}\frac{1}{(2n+1)2^{2n}}+\sum_{m=1}^{M}\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m\;27^{m}}.$$
Now, I assume that $4$ arithmetic operation calculator can be used:

Lower bound is easy: $N=3, M=2\implies \ln28>3.33\implies \ln^328>36.926037>36.$

Upper bound: $N=5, M=3\implies \ln28<3.33213+3\sum_{n=6}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)2^{2n}}\implies \ln28<3.33213+\frac{3}{13}\sum_{n=6}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^{n}}\implies\ln28<3.33221\implies\ln^328<36.9997<37.$